# Error configuring CMake for Ethereum project with Visual Studio 2015 Community on Windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, boost, cmake, ethereum

I have visual studio 2015 community version on Windows 10. I downloaded Ethereum project on github and tried running 
    CMake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 ARM"
command but it failed with following message. (The failing step seems to be the installation of Boost through hunter):

```
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Performing Test fstack-protector-strong
-- Performing Test fstack-protector-strong - Failed
-- Performing Test Wimplicit-fallthrough
-- Performing Test Wimplicit-fallthrough - Failed
-- [hunter] Calculating Toolchain-SHA1
-- [hunter] Calculating Config-SHA1
-- [hunter] HUNTER_ROOT: C:/.hunter
-- [hunter] [ Hunter-ID: b96750b | Toolchain-ID: bb3d68a | Config-ID: 59ec5bb ]
-- [hunter] BOOST_ROOT: C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Install (ver.: 1.64.0)
-- [hunter] Building Boost
loading initial cache file C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/cache.cmake
loading initial cache file C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/args.cmake
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.15063.0 to target Windows 10.0.16299.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe -- works
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_arm/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 11/27/2017 11:33:03 AM.
Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "ARM\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\".
  Creating directory "ARM\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "ARM\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  Checking Build System
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "ARM\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "ARM\Debug\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).
Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (1) is building "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
PrepareForBuild:
  Creating directory "ARM\Debug\Boost\".
  Creating directory "ARM\Debug\Boost\Boost.tlog\".
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "ARM\Debug\Boost\Boost.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
ComputeCustomBuildOutput:
  Creating directory "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost-prefix\src\Boost-stamp\Debug\".
  Creating directory "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\CMakeFiles\Debug\".
CustomBuild:
  Building Custom Rule C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
  Creating directories for 'Boost'
  Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'Boost'
  -- Boost download command succeeded.  See also C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-download-*.log
  No update step for 'Boost'
  No patch step for 'Boost'
  Performing configure step for 'Boost'
  -- Boost configure command succeeded.  See also C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-configure-*.log
  No build step for 'Boost'
  Performing install step for 'Boost'
  CMake Error at C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-Debug.cmake:16 (message):
    Command failed: 1

     'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-Dmake=' '-Dconfig=Debug' '-P' 'C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-Debug-impl.cmake'

    See also

      C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-*.log


C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost.vcxproj" (default target) (3) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\.hunter\_Base\b96750b\bb3d68a\59ec5bb\Build\Boost\Build\Boost.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:01:53.05

[hunter ** FATAL ERROR **] Build step failed (dir: C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost
[hunter ** FATAL ERROR **] [Directory:C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/projects/Boost]

------------------------------ WIKI -------------------------------
    https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/error.external.build.failed
-------------------------------------------------------------------

CMake Error at C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_wiki.cmake:12 (message):
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_fatal_error.cmake:20 (hunter_wiki)
  C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_download.cmake:596 (hunter_fatal_error)
  C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/projects/Boost/hunter.cmake:272 (hunter_download)
  C:/.hunter/_Base/Download/Hunter/0.19.105/b96750b/Unpacked/cmake/modules/hunter_add_package.cmake:53 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:101 (hunter_add_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Alan/Documents/Projects/cpp-ethereum/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Alan/Documents/Projects/cpp-ethereum/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

----------------------------Boost-install-err.log-----------------------
CMake Error at C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-Debug-impl.cmake:9 (message):
  Command failed (The system cannot find the file specified):

   'b2' '--layout=tagged' '-d0' 'install' '--without-atomic' '--without-chrono' '--without-container' '--without-context' '--without-coroutine' '--without-coroutine2' '--without-date_time' '--without-exception' '--without-fiber' '--without-filesystem' '--without-graph' '--without-graph_parallel' '--without-iostreams' '--without-locale' '--without-log' '--without-math' '--without-metaparse' '--without-mpi' '--without-program_options' '--without-python' '--without-random' '--without-regex' '--without-serialization' '--without-signals' '--without-system' '--without-test' '--without-thread' '--without-timer' '--without-type_erasure' '--without-wave' '--prefix=C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Install' '--ignore-site-config'
```

**??In Boost-install-err.log, which file the system couldn't find? b2.exe? The folder 'C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Install' only contains a subfolder call 'lib'. Is it suppose to contain 'the' file that the command is looking for?**

Comment: Don't you see that it is Boost install step that failed? You probably need administrator permissions to install it, as CMake installs into `C:\Program Files\` by default.

Comment: Hint: when you have some error, try to locate the first line where something goes wrong. Errors after that one are probably a consequence of the first error during the process.

Comment: @arrowd Yeah I know it's boost install step that failed as I stated that in my description. And I ran the command prompt in adminstration mode. Are you suggesting installing boost mannually? I am new to c++

Comment: @Pac0 The first line where something goes wrong is CMake Error at C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-Debug.cmake:16 (message):
    Command failed: 1

     'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-Dmake=' '-Dconfig=Debug' '-P' 'C:/.hunter/_Base/b96750b/bb3d68a/59ec5bb/Build/Boost/Build/Boost-prefix/src/Boost-stamp/Boost-install-Debug-impl.cmake' which has the error log on the last paragraph, but that's where I don't understand which file the command failed to find.